# 02 Civic SiR "faint whistling" sound under load

Tags: honda, acceleration, intake

I'm getting what I can best describe as a "faint whistling" sound, mostly under load, sometimes faintly when revving in neutral.  I'd liken it to someone blowing a referee's whistle way off in the distance.

I just got this car, so I've done a bit of maintenance:

- changed oil and filter
- filled maintenance battery and charged up
- checked other fluids (good)
- checked air filter (not too bad shape, but I'll replace it today)

Serpentine belts could probably use replacing.  Everything is stock.  I fill with 91 octane.  Is this just a normal sound made by the intake?

Edit: **[recording of sound](https://streamable.com/vyncd)**

Comment: This may just be turbo noise or you may have a leak in on of the pipes between the turbo and the engine when they are under pressure.

Comment: K20A3 doesn't have a turbo.  I checked the air and vacuum lines, I can't find an obvious leak anywhere.

Comment: Updated with **[recording of sound](https://streamable.com/vyncd)**